# jQuery replaceWith works but prepend does'nt?

Tags: jquery

Line of bug is this:

```
contxt.replaceWith(safe_copy[id]).prepend("<span class='error'>"+jsonObj.data+"</span>");
```

While the `replaceWith` statement works just fine the data is not getting '`prepended`'.

A more complete code:

```
contxt = $(this).parents('div[style^="display"]');
id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
                url: "/submit/myposts",
                type: "POST",
                data: "action=edit&post="+$(this).attr('id').match(/[0-9]+/)[0]+"&data="+encodeURIComponent(text),
                success: function(data){
                    loading.remove();
                    jsonObj = $.parseJSON(data);

                    if(jsonObj.code == "0")
                        block.html(jsonObj.data);
                    else
                        contxt.replaceWith(safe_copy[id]).prepend("<span class='error'>"+jsonObj.data+"</span>");
                },
                error: function(){
                    loading.remove();
                    contxt.replaceWith(safe_copy[id]).prepend("<span class='error'>An error occurred. Please try again.</span>");
                }
            });
```

Comment: does firebug outputs any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.replaceWith()` returns the original jQuery object (the one removed from the page) so when you chain onto it, it will operate on the content that was removed, not the content that was added.

From [the jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) for `.replaceWith()`:

> The .replaceWith() method, like most jQuery methods, returns the
>   jQuery object so that other methods can be chained onto it. However,
>   it must be noted that the original jQuery object is returned. This
>   object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not
>   the new element that has replaced it.

I'm not entirely sure I understand your code/HTML, but this might be one possible work-around:

```
var newContent = $(safe_copy[id]).prepend("<span class='error'>"+jsonObj.data+"</span>");
contxt.replaceWith(newContent);
```

Comment: You can prepend to the new content into the new content BEFORE doing the replaceWith and then replace with the preprended content already in place.  I don't follow what all your variables are or the HTML structure is well enough to suggest the exact code.  Or, you can do the replace() and then find the new content in the page again to do the preprend.

Answer (score 0):

I suspected the following two issues:

```
a. Either the object being returned by replaceWith() was not same as the new node added, or
b. The return object was being regenerated using the original selection criteria
```

It turns out that you still have handle to the original object, which was yanked out of DOM. This is confirmed in the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

You just need to run the selection to get reference to the new node again and then run your prepend operation.  You cannot chain prepend to replaceWith() for the scenario you described.  Check out the following fiddle example showing that this approach works:

http://jsfiddle.net/shaikhtabrez/BbgXW/7/